# How to detect Permission Set Assignments deletion?

Tags: profile, sobject, permission-sets, developer, monitoring

I am currently trying to **detect changes in permission set assignments within an arbitrary period**; it implies creation and deletion. Where profile and permission set assignment creation is straight forward to detect using the `PermissionSetAssignment` table and conditions on the `SystemModStamp` field, deletion is harder.

Indeed, `PermissionSetAssignment` records don't support the `getDeleted` call to fetch relationship ids that were removed, and `queryAll` acts as `query` yielding the same records without the `isDeleted` field.

For profiles specifically, I was thinking about a partial solution where I could monitor the `User` records and watch for changes in the `ProfileId` field, but it does necessarily scale well. For permission sets, I have no workaround at the moment.

In summary, is there a way to **detect profile and permission set assignments deletion**?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need this detection mechanism? What problem are you trying to solve? Please read about the [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/), which may be applicable here.

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox, thanks for the quick response! I am working on a third-party system that checks for changes in Salesforce permissions (who can see what). Because profiles and permission sets are crucial to those permissions, I need to know which users are assigned to them and track changes over time.

EDIT: I want to know which users have read access to which objects, therefore looking at profile and permission set changes. Because they are so many users it is not efficient to do a full table scan of the assignment table.

Comment: I understand your desire better now, but this just isn't possible. Salesforce permissions are not really meant to be usable outside of Salesforce in the general sense, which is why there's only limited support in the API for them compared to standard objects. A constant sweep would be the only way to do this today. You'll want to vote on [this Idea](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DrBwAAK).